# -webkit-fill-available is taking 0 height

Tags: css, reactjs, debugging, tailwind-css

I am using -webkit-fill-available for the 'min-height' property for my web app in React, however it is compiling to a height of 0, despite the fact I also have 'min-height: 100vh' above it.

```css
.min-safe-h-screen {
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

[image]

This problem is happening in Chrome on desktop,, as well as on my iPhone safari browser.

However, it works perfectly fine on Firefox, both with and without `-moz-fill-available`. Strangely, with `-moz-fill-available` but *without* `-webkit-fill-available`, it does not work on Firefox as well.

Edit: It works on Firefox except in some weird cases.